# How to reset the background of a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

After adding a background (image) to my UIView (View_0) I wish to implement a button to remove the same background.

How can I do it? I have tried to set a different image as the background of View_0 but this does not work (I suspect this background is set behind "image").

I don't want to use

```
[View_0 removeFromSuperview];
```

as I need View_0 to still be there for other purposes....

```
//Create an ImageView
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 940, 422)];;           

//Add the ImageView as the background of the View_0
[View_0 addSubview:image];
//Move custom image behind View
[View_0 sendSubviewToBack: image];

//Failed attempt to remove the background....
View_0.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage.PNG"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added a UIImageView to the View and Not the background of the view. So what is happening is that when u implement

```
View_0.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage.PNG"]];
```

The background of the View is being set but the UIImageView is now on top of the View so that is why the background of the View is not being shown.

Instead if you simply want to add the background you can change it to the Action of the UIButton.

Also if you use `[View_0 removeFromSuperview];` you are trying to remove the view which is not right.

Answer (score 1):

```
  //Create an ImageView
        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 940, 422)];;  
        image.tag = 1234;         

        //Add the ImageView as the background of the View_0
        [View_0 addSubview:image];
        //Move custom image behind View
        [View_0 sendSubviewToBack: image];

        UIImageView *imgView = [self.view viewWithTag:1234];
        [img setImage:nil];
```

This should work i think

Comment: That is because you are removing the image completely. Simply keep both of them and set imageview.hidden = YES when you dont want one.